# Zombiejs cucumberjs upload file error

Tags: node.js, zombie.js, cucumberjs

I am working on a Node/React/Redux project using cucumberjs for testing. I set up the tests using the [cucumberjs github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) page. I've got the basic zombie tests working to click buttons, fill out forms, assert text etc. The libraries are really awesome and working for the basic Use Cases.

I'm having problems with a file upload page. The page works fine in manual tests. Here's how I'm trying to attach the file in my cuc tests:

```
 browserShare.attach('input[type=file]', 'features/csv_files/amex-5.csv');
 browserShare.assert.text('.alert','File selected: amex-5.csv');
```

When running the tests, the console gives the following error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection [ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined]
```

My question is: Is this the correct way to attach a file to an input, am I doing something wrong with the zombie/cucumber script? Hoping someone can help, let me know if you need any more code samples, it's basically set up just like the github link above. Thanks in advance!